# how can i get the values using include with conditions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the shop with has_many association and include items to it so that the items belonging to that shop is received

```
 format.json { render json: {:shop => @shops.as_json(:include => :items)}}
```

now it gives all the items that belongs to that shop but i want to get items with specific condition, say item_type = "accessories". so how can i do this? please help me.

**EDIT**

I have put a new question in [How to get the value of include with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829497/how-to-get-the-value-of-include-with-conditions/15829781?noredirect=1#comment22520103_15829781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the data with ActiveRecord, and then call the as_json on the filtered data.

You can do something like:

```
@shops = Shop.includes(:items).where("items.itemp_type = ?", 'accesories')
format.json { render json: { :shop => @shops.as_json(:include => :items) } }
```

Comment: sorry, but another doubt. If i have item_types in a seperate table and i specify the id of the item_type in that item table for reference and i want to specify condition like accesories is "available" and display if it is available. how should i do it?

Comment: I'm having problems to understand your question, create a new question where you can put the code for your models (just the relationships between them) and the filtering you want to do, and then I will gladly help with the query.

Comment: I have put a new question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829497/how-to-get-the-value-of-include-with-conditions.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to create a hash with the objects you want to render, and then pass that to the render method. Like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render :json => {:shops => @shops, 
                                  :items => @items }}
end
```

If the models aren't associated through active record, that's probably your best solution.

If an association does exist, you can pass an `:include argument to the render call`, like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render :json => @shops.to_json(:include => [:items])}
end
```

Note that you wouldn't have to retrieve the @items variable in the section above if you take this approach, Rails will automatically load it from the `@shops` variable.